# $E[m(X)h(X)]=0$ for every $m(X)$ implies $h(X)=0$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question as follows: $m(X)$ and $h(X)$ are functions of a random variable X. If we know that $E[m(X)h(X)]=0$ for every $m(X)$, does this imply that $h(X)=0$, a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take $m=h$. Of course, we can only conclude that $h(X)=0$ almost surely.